# jqtouch div page load old data

Tags: javascript, cordova, jqtouch

In an android app that I am am working on, I am using jqtouch.  As you know, for jqtouch, it will switch in between pages defined in div.

Here I have a code as below so when a next button is click, it will go to #start page.

```
<a id="continue" style="margin-bottom: 120px" href="#start" onclick="loadDb(this.id)" class="whiteButton slide">Continue</a>"
```

However at times, when the continue button is clicked, it seems that loadDb is not called and the #start page is not updated with the new data loaded using loadDb.  It will display previous data in the page.  Looks like it is a cached page.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Many thx!

Comment: Sorry the code was not indented properly.  Just edited it.

Comment: Anyone could help on the above question?  Thx.